# Expected a value of type 'JavaScriptObject', but got one of type 'Null'

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-authentication

I randomly started getting this error in my Flutter app when trying to call `await FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser?.getIdTokenResult()` on Flutter web.

> Expected a value of type 'JavaScriptObject', but got one of type
> 'Null'

Has anyone else seen this?

My app uses firebase-auth: 4.11.0

---

## Edit

Here is the associated GitHub issue:

https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12238

Comment: the user was loged-in correctly ? or try this with user logout and then login . will be better if you post the [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: [currentUser](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/currentUser.html) is known to be null when the user is not yet fully signed in.  You need to use an [auth state observer](https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_auth/latest/firebase_auth/FirebaseAuth/authStateChanges.html) to know when the user information has been verified after the app starts up.  See more in the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/flutter/start#auth-state).

Comment: No I understand how to use Firebase. This is the issue: https://github.com/firebase/flutterfire/issues/12238